# Select Query Failing in Execute Sql Task but not in DFT

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dataflowtask

I have a select query in Execute SQL TASK(EST) like

```
select * from table
```

The result set is "Full Result" and assigned to an object variable. When I execute the task, it fails and throws error saying

```
"SSIS debug host has stopped working"
```

The same query if I run in Data Flow Task(DFT), query runs successfully and I am able to dump data into another table.

Is there any difference between their execution in EST and DFT ? IF yes, is there any workaround to make that query run in EST.

Thanks in Advance for the help.

Comment: A few question: Did you add variables for this? What's the type of the variable? Did you add the variable as result set in the SQL Task?

Comment: how many rows does this query return?

Comment: Could you post the definition of the table/resultset you are receiving? Have you ensured your tooling (Visual Studio and SQL Server) are patched up to date? What if you run the SSIS package outside the debug process (Shift-F5) Does it work then?